# error with an url that does not exist in my project in django

Tags: django, http-status-code-500

I was having this issue just in my production environment. I have an icon that is in my static files. I can load it through https://mydomain/static/img/favico.ico, but at the same time I get a 500 error for the following url https://mydomain/favico.ico . <- this url does not exist in my project.

I can't replicate in my local environment. I already did collectstatic.

Comment: maybe wrong in settings file in `STATIC_URL` ?

Comment: Have you checked your logs to determine where the 500 error comes from? You should have 3 logs to check: the web server (apache or nginx), your app server (gunicorn or uwsgi or mod_wsgi) and your django app (`LOGGING` settings)

Answer (score 3):

The default favicon URL is `/favicon.ico`.

You should change it in your template to what you need:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'img/favico.png' %}"/>
```

make change in `href` and `type` according to your favicon file.